# SQL - Time serie - Return 0 for missing values

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, time-series

I have a MS/Azure SQL table, called MY_TABLE (for instance) that contains two columns:

- datetime : INT = UNIX epoch (date and time of the measurement)
- val : DECIMAL (measured value)

This table represents a time serie, typically in 1 min resolution. There could be some gap / missing value in the data. The SQL database is linked to a Django web application where the time serie will be displayed on a chart.

I use the following query to retrieve aggregated data in 1h resolution, between two dates:

```
    WITH time_table as (
        SELECT cast(dateadd(second, datetime, '19700101') as DATETIME) as calendar_date,val,datetime as epoch
        FROM MY_TABLE
        WHERE datetime>=1451628000 and datetime<1452755200
    )
    SELECT min(epoch),avg(val) 
    FROM time_table
    GROUP BY YEAR(calendar_date),MONTH(calendar_date),DAY(calendar_date),datepart(hour,calendar_date)
    ORDER BY min(calendar_date) ASC
```

This query returns the average values aggregated over 1h time periods.

Questions

1. How can I modify this query to a value (0) at all time steps even if there is no corresponding data in the table. To be more clear, I want the result to be a continuous time serie without any gap in time

I could easily perform this operation using Python/Pandas but I feel that would not be optimized

Comment: I would create a temp table that contains a listing of time and join it with the query you have in the question.

Comment: It is not totally clear what the issue is but I think you are wanting to return a row when one doesn't exist. In order to do that you need a table that has every value you want returned. Make that the primary table of your query and then do a left join to your values.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer ! I am not super familiar with SQL : how can I generate a zero-valued table for each time between two dates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate a table of hours with the Epoch form and datetime form:

```
create table dbo.Hours (
   EpochStart bigint not null primary key clustered
 , EpochEnd   bigint not null
 , Datetime_Hour datetime not null
 , Datetime_NextHour datetime not null
);

declare @fromdate datetime = '20160101';
declare @thrudate datetime = '20161231';

;with n as (select n from (values(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) t(n))
, Hours as (
  select top ((datediff(day, @fromdate,@thrudate)+1)*24)
      [Datetime_Hour]=convert(datetime,dateadd(hour,row_number() over(order by (select 1))-1,@fromdate))
     ,[Datetime_NextHour]=convert(datetime,dateadd(hour,row_number() over(order by (select 1)),@fromdate))
  from n as deka cross join n as hecto cross join n as kilo 
                cross join n as tenK cross join n as hundredK
   order by 1
)
insert into dbo.Hours
select
   EpochStart = datediff(second,'19700101',Datetime_Hour)
 , EpochEnd   = datediff(second,'19700101',Datetime_NextHour)
 , Datetime_Hour
 , Datetime_NextHour
from Hours;
```

Then use it in your query like so:

```
select 
   h.EpochStart
 , avg(val)
from dbo.Hours h
  left join MY_TABLE t
    on t.datetime >= h.EpochStart
   and t.datetime <  h.EpochEnd
where h.EpochStart >= 1451628000
  and h.EpochStart <  1452755200
group by h.EpochStart
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/INZW16141